# get data from related tables in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

assuming these 3 tables

```sql
create table item(
    item_id integer NOT NULL primary key,
    name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    description varchar(150) NOT NULL,
    in_stock integer NOT NULL
)

create table customer(
    customer_id VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL primary key,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    phone VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    join_date DATE NOT NULL
)

create table purchase(
    purchase_id integer references item,
    customer_id varchar(9) references customer,
    purchase_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    amount INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(purchase_id, customer_id, purchase_date)
)
```

- how could I get each unique name and the total amount of items purchased?
- how could I get each purchase name and the buyer's name and lastname?
- how could I get each item and how many of it were sold?

Answer (score 0):

The two topics you are looking to learn are how to use GROUP BY and how to JOIN tables. Here's an example (more or less) that answers your first question and uses both tools:

```
select 
  C.customer_id as customer_id,
  max(C.name) as customer_name,
  sum(amount) as total_amount
from customer C
left join purchase P on C.customer_id = P.customer_id
group by C.customer_id
```